# How to set Png Border Image correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a png to be the bottom border of one div and again at the top of my footer. I've tried border-image as well as using it as the background image for my div, but I've failed to figure it out. Right now I'm just getting a black bar at the bottom of my first div, and a little black mark at the top of my Footer. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code so far.

**Main Page**

```
    <div className='about-wrapper'>
    <img src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/gorilla-thinking-260nw-54482215.jpg' alt='Adam Face'></img>
    <h2>Name</h2>
    <p>Welcome to my site! I am a developer currently developing in ReactJS.</p>
  </div>

 .about-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-image: url('https://ubisafe.org/images/detorted-clipart-sky-line-1.png') 1%;
  background: linear-gradient(#519DFE, #110BFF);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}
```

**Footer**

```
<div className='footer-wrapper'>
  </div>


    .footer-wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  background: #001ED4;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-image: url('https://ubisafe.org/images/detorted-clipart-sky-line-1.png') 1%;
```

**Here's what my pages look like**

[First Div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZttV.png)

[Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV25p.png)

Comment: What does your HTML look like? You might just need to add a width to the CSS.

Comment: The First div is just a div with a h1 a p tag and an img, my Footer is just an empty div. ive added it to the post if you want to look.

Comment: What does `1%` mean in you border-bottom definition?

Comment: @MrLister border-image-slice property i believe. without it the border image doesn't even show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `border-image-slice` property indicates which parts of the image are used for the border; with only a single value, it will the same percentage of the width and height for the slices.

[image]

(Note that I used about 10% in my illustration to make it clear, but it works the same for 1%.) Since you have only a border bottom for the about-wrapper div, only the bottom part will be used.

So if you want the entire picture for a bottom border, the solution is to not use an 1% image slice. You would need `0 0 100% 0` (for top, right, bottom, left respectively). Same with the footer: for the top border there, use `100% 0 0 0`.

```css
.about-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-image: url('https://ubisafe.org/images/detorted-clipart-sky-line-1.png') 0 0 100% 0;
  background: #110BFF linear-gradient(#519DFE, #110BFF);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

.footer-wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  background: #001ED4;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-image: url('https://ubisafe.org/images/detorted-clipart-sky-line-1.png') 100% 0 0 0;
```

```html
<div class='about-wrapper'>
  <img src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/gorilla-thinking-260nw-54482215.jpg' alt='Adam Face'>
  <h2>Name</h2>
  <p>Welcome to my site! I am a developer currently developing in ReactJS.</p>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->

<div class='footer-wrapper'>
</div>
```